# Arrow key Input without pausing console

Tags: c++, input, console

I'm currently writing a little snake game in the console to get used to c++ but I can't seem to find a good way to get arrow key inputs without pausing the console. does anyone know a way I could get arrow key inputs and not have the console pausing?

Comment: no because this pauses my game because it waits for an input and doesn't allow the game to continue running. I need a solution that allows everything to continue. (I was thinking maybe some kind of callback function so the waiting for an input can be done while the program is running.

Comment: You might be able to try threading.

Comment: I don't have much experience with that and neither do I have much c++ experience but i will try it. It seems like it would be a good solution.

Comment: It has worked!!! I have just put the code that looks for the input in a separate function and made a thread at the beginning which executes this function and when the function is done it just calls itself again. It worked like a charm.